# Manipulating cookies after sending response on Plone 4.3

Tags: plone, zope, plone-4.x, zope.component

I need to change data stored inside cookies, or set new cookies when a user access a Plone URL.

The official Plone documentation contains exactly what I need in the [Modifying HTTP response cookies](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/sessions/cookies.html#modifying-http-response-cookies) section.

Unluckily it seems to be a deprecated documentation as it's need the [plone.postpublicationhook](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.postpublicationhook/) package, not shipped with Plone and only needed For Zope < 2.12; documentation says: "*This package is provided for backwards compatibility. New code should use the publication events introduced in Zope 2.12 directly.*"

As I'm using Plone 4.3/Zope 2.13 I'm wondering if there's a way to do not include this deprecated package.

I'm trying to use the `ZPublisher.interfaces` events without any success.

I'm trying a ZCML registration like this:

```
  <adapter
      factory=".mymodule.my_cookie_handler_function"
      provides="ZPublisher.interfaces.IPubSuccess"
      />
```

But the function is never called.

Some examples/codes I found (but still can't reach my scope):

- https://www.nathanvangheem.com/news/notes-on-a-more-secure-plone-deployment
- http://sourceforge.net/p/plone/mailman/message/23959870/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I see code that's use adapters, it seems you must provide a `subscriber` instead.

This worked:

```
  <subscriber
      handler=".mymodule.my_cookie_handler_function"
      for="ZPublisher.interfaces.IPubSuccess"
      />
```

Not sure if `IPubSuccess` is the "right" interface to use.

Comment: Before accepting this as right one I hope some guys can explain me how use adapters instead or the difference between this approach.